# Intiliaze a component with properties inside an object in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a data class for storing properties

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache")
data class CacheProperties(
    var enable: Boolean = false,
    var CacheName: String = "",
)
```

And I have an object where I need to use these properties. The Kotlin `object` doesn't support the @Autowired annotation. How can I initialize the properties in this case?

```
object MdsCacheValidationUtil {

    //need to inject cache properties here

    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    fun validateLastUpdateTime(lastUpdateTime: Instant?) {
        println(cache.CacheName)
        //.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn `MdsCacheValidationUtil` into a Spring Managed Bean using `@Component` annotation as follows:

```kotlin
@Component
class MdsCacheValidationUtil(cacheProperties: CacheProperties) {

    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    fun validateLastUpdateTime(lastUpdateTime: Instant?) {
        println(cacheProperties.CacheName)
        //.....
    }
}
```

Additionally, I believe you have a typo in `CacheProperties`. I guess you wanted to write `cacheName` instead of `CacheName`. Mind the lowercase "c".

Comment: You are welcome! If it solved your problem you can accept it as the answer to your question so that others that come across this question understand what a solution could be ;)